# ramda evolve function example

Tags: javascript, functional-programming, ramda.js

From Ramda Repl:

```
var tomato  = {firstName: '  Tomato ', data: {elapsed: 100, remaining: 1400}, id:123};
```

Why does this work:

```
var transformations = {
  firstName: ()=>'Potato'
};
// => {"data": {"elapsed": 100, "remaining": 1400}, "firstName": "Potato", "id": 123}
```

But this doesnt:

```
var transformations = {
  firstName:'Potato'
};
//=>{"data": {"elapsed": 100, "remaining": 1400}, "firstName": "  Tomato ", "id": 123}
```

R.evolve(transformations, tomato);

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> [`R.evolve`](http://ramdajs.com/docs/#evolve)
>
> Creates a new object by recursively evolving a shallow copy of `object`, according to the `transformation` **functions**. All non-primitive properties are copied by reference.
>
> A `transformation` **function** will not be invoked if its corresponding key does not exist in the evolved object.

In short, the transformation must be a **function**.

> Why does this work:
>
> ```
> var transformations = {
>   firstName: ()=>'Potato'
> };
> ```

Because `()=>'Potato'` is a *function*

> But this doesnt:
>
> ```
> var transformations = {
>   firstName:'Potato'
> };
> ```

Because `'Potato'` is a *string*, **not a function**.

In such a case when the provided transformation is not a function, the original value.

Here's the source code for [`evolve`](https://github.com/ramda/ramda/blob/v0.23.0/src/evolve.js#L37). I **bolded** the code path your example takes to arrive at the output

```
module.exports = _curry2(function evolve(transformations, object) {
  var result = {};
  var transformation, key, type;
  for (key in object) {
    transformation = transformations[key];
    type = typeof transformation;
    result[key] = type === 'function'                 ? transformation(object[key])
                : transformation && type === 'object' ? evolve(transformation, object[key])
                                                      : object[key];
  }
  return result;
});
```

Comment: Was drafting the exact same answer before I saw yours... The only thing I wanted to add is a link to the source that shows what happens when you pass something that's not a `function` nor an `object`: it returns `object[key]` (line 39) https://github.com/ramda/ramda/blob/v0.23.0/src/evolve.js#L37

Answer (score 1):

@naomik's explained why - but if for some reason you *need* to use evolve, you could do:

```
{
    firstName: R.always('Potato')
}
```

It's worth remembering that the argument given to the transform is the current value, and if the key doesn't exist it won't add anything.